# How to determine final uncompressed size of a zip in batch or vbscript?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, zip

Hi I'm building my own antivirus in batch and want to add a zip bomb or decompression bomb detecting feature, how would I determine final uncompressed size of a zip in batch or vbscript?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can query the command line archiver to get the total filesize.  Which archiver are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any particular archiver for my program. Could the one embedded in windows explorer be accessed from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save this as `.bat`:

```
 @if (@x)==(@y) @end /***** jscript comment ******
     @echo off

     cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"  %*
     exit /b 0

 @if (@x)==(@y) @end ******  end comment *********/


 var wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
var args=WScript.Arguments;
var zipFile=args.Item(0);

    getSize = function(path){
        var ShellObj=new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
        var targetObject = new Object;
        var targetObject=ShellObj.NameSpace(path);

        if (typeof size === 'undefined'){
            var size=0;
        }
        if (targetObject != null ){

            for (var i=0; i<targetObject.Items().Count;i++){
                //WScript.Echo("Checking: "+targetObject.Items().Item(i));
                if(!targetObject.Items().Item(i).IsFolder){
                    size=size+targetObject.Items().Item(i).Size;
                } else if (targetObject.Items().Item(i).Count!=0){
                    size=size+getSize(targetObject.Items().Item(i).Path);
                }
            }
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
        return size;
    }



WScript.Echo(getSize(zipFile));
```

It takes only one argument - the zip file and prints its size in bytes. (the `Item.Size` property gets the uncompressed size)

**EDIT**  it does not work with relative paths.Full paths should be used.
**EDIT** [zipjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/zipjs.bat) (introduced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compres-zip-and-uncopress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-batch-f) ) can be used for this purpose:

```
call zipjs.bat getSize -source C:\\zipFile.zip
```

and no longer full path is required and a relative one can be used.

Comment: @Towtow10 - try with the full path.Apparently it does not work with relative paths.

Comment: I was already using the full path but I tried relative and it worked thanks.

Comment: I'd change line 5 to `exit /b %errorlevel%` so that the exit code of the VBScript is passed to the caller.

Comment: For some reason when I run this program inside my program it stops the main program. Can you fix this?

Comment: @Towtow10 - what you mean with main program? How do you call the script? From batch file?

Comment: @npocmaka no I can call it from my batch file when your script finishes running it closes my batch file.

Comment: @Towtow10 - Have you used `CALL` when the other batch call this one?

Comment: @npocmaka - Thanks that worked, but can I have the output as a variable instead of printing it to the screen?

Comment: `for /f %%a in ('getSizeZip.bat  c:\some.zip ') do set size=%%a`

Comment: @npocmaka what is the output variable for your code

Comment: That worked but your code does not go all the way through the zip bomb, it only calculates the first layer. A zip bomb is an archive which has more archives in it and each of those have more archives and more archives and at the end in each archive is a really large file say 4 gb, the zip bomb I'm testing on should come to well over 4 billion gb. is there any way you can modify your code to detect this?

Comment: @Towtow10 - No.`Shell.Application` sees a zip file as a directory but the zip files inside a zip are taken as a files so cannot be traversed.But if you use `Shell.Application` for unzip the zip bomb will not work as it can unzip only on level1.